# Delete records from Hive table using filename

Tags: hive

I have a use case where I build a hive table from a bunch of csv files. While writing csv information into hive table, I assign `INPUT__FILE__NAME` (part of the name) to one of the columns. When I want to the update the records for the same filename, I need to delete the records of the `csv` file before writing it again.

I use the below query but failed

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE T_TEMP_CSV(    
        F_FRAME_RANK BIGINT,
        F_FRAME_RATE BIGINT,
        F_SOURCE STRING,
        F_PARAMETER STRING,
        F_RECORDEDVALUE STRING,
        F_VALIDITY INT,
        F_VALIDITY_INTERPRETATION STRING)         
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'       
    location '/user/baamarna5617/HUMS/csv'
    TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="2"); 


DELETE FROM T_RECORD       
  WHERE T_RECORD.F_SESSION = split(reverse(split(reverse(T_TEMP_CSV.INPUT__FILE__NAME),"/")[0]), "[.]")[0] 
         from T_TEMP_CSV;
```

The `T_RECORD` table has a column called `F_SESSION` which was assigned part of the `INPUT__FILE__NAME` using the split method shown above. I want to use the same method while removing those records. Can someone please point me where i am going wrong in this query?

I could successfully delete the records using the below syntax

```
 DELETE FROM T_RECORD 
    WHERE F_SESSION = 68;
```

I need to get that 68 from the `INPUT_FILE_NAME`.

Comment: Why don't you just delete the file? It's much faster than deleting records from table.

Comment: In our use case, I have created one internal table out of bunch of csv files (Let's say, A, B, C) stored in hdfs. Sometimes, we receive from our client a revised A file for which we need to update the internal table. Hence, I thought of removing the records of A from the internal table and insert. Hence, I followed this approach.

Comment: Ok, then delete file A first then add new records(add new file file A or INSERT). This is faster than UPDATE.

Comment: I read that deleting the file will not delete the data in managed table. I have created a managed table. You suggest to create an external table?

Comment: Managed or external, Delete a file will delete it's records in any table. Because records data is stored in files. The difference between managed and external: Drop external table will not delete files. Drop managed table will drop files.

Comment: I am sorry. But I have created this managed table by manipulating some of the columns using INSERT command. Hence, deleting the file will not affect the data managed by Hive. For this, first i created one external table with the same columns as in csv file, created one internal table, and then insert values (manipulated) from external table into internal table.

Comment: You say: "Hence, deleting the file will not affect the data managed by Hive" The only data I know that will be not affected by deleting files is table statistics data in the metastore. After manipulating files you may need to gather statistics if necessary. This applies to both managed and external tables.

Comment: Understood now. Thanks. Can i delete hdfs directory using HiveQL? If not,  i use 'overwrite'

Comment: You cannot. Only using hadoop fs -rm ... command. Consider delete files or drop partitions instead of Overwrite because it is faster.

Comment: Thank you. I take your suggestion.